# How to make login when user is signing up to a system

Tags: php, mysql

Presently in my login system a user has to do login after sign up.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <p>Not a member yet?.Sign up here.By Sign up You are accepting our <a href="terms.php">terms and conditions</a> </p>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Registration Info</legend>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php if (!empty($username)) echo $username; ?>" /><br />
      <label for="email">Email id:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" /><br />
      <label for="password1">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1" /><br />
      <label for="password2">Password (retype):</label>
      <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" /><br />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="create" />
  </form>
```

If the form submitted correctly

```
<?php
      if (!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password)) {
 // Make sure someone isn't already registered using this username
  $query = "SELECT * FROM <database> WHERE username = '$username'";
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
    // The username is unique, so insert the data into the database
    $query = "INSERT INTO <database> (username,last_name,password,join_date) VALUES ('$username','$email',SHA('$password1'), NOW())";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("cant create an account");
    }else{
        die("Somthing went wrong");
    }
      }
?>
```

Once it is done he has to go to login page and requerd to login using the following codes

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Log In</legend>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if (!empty($user_username)) echo $user_username; ?>" /><br />
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="submit" />
  </form>
```

I dont want this system happend like this when the user is signing up that time itself the user has to be taken to home page. And the session variables also has to be setted while signing up process.

Comment: There should be few codes for handing login, copy that codes and past it in `if (!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password)) {` condition, **before redirection on login page** and comment the redirection for login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reuse the code, it will help to manage your code and application , Please create a function for login process, and use the same function for normal login and after signup then call the same function with the details used for signup.

```
function authenticate($user_id, $pwd)
{
 // do the logic for login, 
 //if success then set value in session and  redirect to the respective page
 //if failed then error page
}



  if (!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password)) {
 // Make sure someone isn't already registered using this username
  $query = "SELECT * FROM <database> WHERE username = '$username'";
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
    // The username is unique, so insert the data into the database
    $query = "INSERT INTO <database> (username,last_name,password,join_date) VALUES ('$username','$email',SHA('$password1'), NOW())";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("cant create an account");
    // call the authenticate function for login
    authenticate($username, SHA('$password1'));
    }else{
        die("Somthing went wrong");
    }
      }
```

Comment: How to take the signup values to that function when it is already added to the database?. Or if you can show one example what you meant me to do?.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :-

```
<?php
      if (!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password)) {
 // Make sure someone isn't already registered using this username
  $query = "SELECT * FROM <database> WHERE username = '$username'";
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
    // The username is unique, so insert the data into the database
    $query = "INSERT INTO <database> (username,last_name,password,join_date) VALUES ('$username','$email',SHA('$password1'), NOW())";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("cant create an account");

    $_SESSION["username"] = $username; // assign session variable here.
    header("Location: home.php");  // redirect to home page

    }else{
        die("Somthing went wrong");
    }
      }
?>
```